# How to display text that is hidden by hover

Tags: html, hover, transition, hidden

My navigation/menu bar doesn't show unless I hover over it. I want to know how to disable this so as the navigation/menu bar is always displayed. (This is for my tumblr layout http://buubbleguum.tumblr.com/ )

Here is the code:

```
#navi
{width:125px;
margin-left:180px;
opacity:1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;-moz-transition: all 1.s ease-out;transition: all 1s ease-out;}

#nav:hover #navi
{margin-left:10px;}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Margin Left and the webkit transition (because no transition is required if you don't have a margin left)

The below code should work

```
#navi{
width:125px;
opacity:1;
}

#nav:hover #navi
{margin-left:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is place the menu at its "final" position as it is after the hover effect takes place.

Change your css to: 
    {width:125px; margin-left:10px; opacity:1;}